# if else if not outputing else if statement java

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I have problem with else if part of the code. First "if" works fine, third (else) works fine, but I have problem with "else if" part of the code, where program don't execute this statement.

```
if ((a+c)>=(b+d)) {
    if ((a==b) && (b==c) && (c==d)) {
        System.out.println("square");
    } else if ( (a!=b) && (c!=d)  && ( a== c) && (b == d)  ) {
        System.out.println("rectangle");
    } else {
        System.out.println("four different sides");
    }
} else
    System.out.println("ERROR");
```

So, when I enter values a=c and b=d, I get "ERROR" instead of "rectangle.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: What exact values are you entering? Just saying "a=c and b=d" is not enough information.

Comment: I find where I made mistake, I put the wrong condition at the start of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution for checking square, rectangle and four sides are different for all sample input

```
 if(a>0 && b>0 && c>0 && d>0)
  {
    if ((a==c) ||(b==d))
    {
        if ((a==b) && (b==c) && (c==d))
        {
            System.out.println("square");
        }
        else if ( (a!=b) && (c!=d)  && ( a== c) && (b == d))
        {
            System.out.println("rectangle");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Two side are same but not square or rectangle");
        }
    }  
    else 
       System.out.println("four different sides");

 } else 
    System.out.println("Error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this condition at the top: 'if ((a+c)>=(b+d))'.
Maybe you are entering  a = c and b = d but it may does not meet this condition '((a+c) >= (b + d)' which is the very first one. Due to which it will go towards else part of first if statement.
For more details share your values which you are entering maybe I can elaborate it a bit more.

Comment: Yes, You are right! I put the wrong condition at the beginning. When I enter a=4, b=5, c=4, d=5 it doesn't work, but with values a=5, b=4, c=5, d=4 it works. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering values a = c and b = d then you have to also check that a or c values are greater then b and d.
In your case, a and c values are smaller then b and d so first if statement doesn't meet the condition.

You can try this for understanding.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 4,b =2 ,c =4 ,d =2;
        if ((a+c)>=(b+d))
        {
            if ((a==b) && (b==c) && (c==d))
            {

                System.out.println("square");

            }
            else if ( (a!=b) && (c!=d)  && ( a== c) && (b == d)  )
            {
                System.out.println("rectangle");
            }

            else
            {

                System.out.println("four different sides");
            }

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your code to this :

```
if ((a + c) >= (b + d)) {
        if ((a == b) && (b == c) && (c == d)) {
            System.out.println("square");
        } else if ((a != b) && (c != d) && (a == c) && (b == d)) {
            System.out.println("rectangle");
        } else {
            System.out.println("four different sides");
        }
    } else if ((a != b) && (c != d) && (a == c) && (b == d)) {
        System.out.println("rectangle");
    } else if (a != b && b != c && c != d && a != c) {
        System.out.println("four different sides");
    } else
        System.out.println("ERROR");
```

Job Done :)

Comment: Thank You! All this brackets confused me.

Comment: @zokistone edited answer please check now . it will work fine

Comment: Please verify as the accepted answer. or give a upvote :)

Comment: Problem is in first condition, I have put the wrong condition. Seems my math is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your first condition if ((a+c)>=(b+d)) is not correct for rectangle condition because
for rectangle both opposite side are equal.If you sum (a+c) it looks like two small side value is never equal to two big side (b+d) value.Similarly if you change a,c as big side and b,d as small side of rectangle condition will be same as before.So you can change like bellow

Sample input for square
int a=2,b=2,c=2,d=2;

Sample input for rectangle
int a=2,b=4,c=2,d=4;

Sample input 
a=10,b=4,c=6,d=9

```
if ((a==c)||(b==d))
        {
            if ((a==b) && (b==c) && (c==d))
            {
                System.out.println("square");
            }
            else if ( (a!=b) && (c!=d)  && ( a== c) && (b == d))
            {
                System.out.println("rectangle");
            }
            else 
            {           
                System.out.println("Two sides are similar but not square or rectangle");
            }

        } else
        System.out.println("Foure side are different");
```

Comment: When four input are different it some time goes to error logic. You need to check it that... try this sample input     int a=10,b=4,c=6,d=9;